# ReactNative + TypeScript + WebStorm - debugging not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webstorm

I have problem with debugging of my ReactNative app written in TypeScript when I use WebStorm IDE.

Application works, but when I put breakpoint to `render` method code never stopped on it.

Here is my tsconfig:

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es5",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "jsx": "react-native",
      "outDir": "artifacts",
      "rootDir": "src",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "allowJs": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
      "typings/index.d.ts",
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "types": [
      "react",
      "react-native",
      "jest"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "android",
      "ios",
      "build",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

and package.json:

```
  {
    "name": "untitled2",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
      "build": "npm run clean && npm run tsc --",
      "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "16.3.1",
      "react-native": "0.55.3",
      "inversify": "^4.13.0",
      "react-navigation": "^1.5.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "typescript": "^2.8.3",
      "tslint": "^5.9.1",
      "@types/react": "^16.3.12",
      "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
      "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
      "jest": "22.4.3",
      "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native",
      "testRegex": "artifacts/.+\\.(test|spec).js$",
      "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
      "coverageReporters": [
        "text-summary",
        "html"
      ]
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "artifacts/**/*.js",
      "!artifacts/**/*.spec.js",
      "!artifacts/**/*.index.js"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I use "debug symbol" to run application and it's default iOS react native configuration from Jetbrains. I add `package.json` configuration to my first question.

Comment: haven't found any official tutorials on this, but seems you still need using [react-native-sm-transformer](https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformerhttps://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer) to add sourcemaps to the bundle. This package is a part of [typescript template](https://github.com/emin93/react-native-template-typescript) available for `react-native init`... see also https://shellmonger.com/2017/08/09/debugging-react-native-with-typescript-and-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js.debugger.break.on.first.statement.with.regexp`  in Registry ( Help | Find Action... | Registry) helps me.

More info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32588